# radio box not calling Javascript function

Tags: javascript, input

I am learning javascript and trying to make a simple option based program.
when a user selects a radio box according to car model is shown. and when user select car model its price should be printed or alerted.
First user option works but second(car models) is not calling my js functions, please help
Here Is the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Modal</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(p) {
      alert(p);
      document.getElementById(p).style.display = "block";
      return 1;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function select(Rs) {
      alert("HAHAHAHAH" + Rs);
      document.write("HAHAHAHAH <br>" + Rs);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  BMW : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="BMW" onclick="show('BMWModels')"><br> Ferrari : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Ferrari" onclick="show('FerrariModels')"><br> Maruti : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Maruti" onclick="show('MarutiModels')"><br>

  <div id="BMWModels" style="display: none">
    <!--HERE IF I WRITE onclick="alert('price for this model is xxxxx ')" 
    then it works properly..-->
    <!-- 
      I tried calling the function from browser console then it works properly please kindly guide me..
    -->
    BMW Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="select(1)"><br> BMW Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br> BMW Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br>

  </div>

  <div id="FerrariModels" style="display: none">
    Ferrari Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br> Ferrari Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br> Ferrari Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br>
  </div>

  <div id="MarutiModels" style="display: none">
    Maruti Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br> Maruti Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br> Maruti Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="select('10000000 Rs')"><br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please, adopt `addEventListener` function `(:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a collection of reserved keywords that you cannot use to name functions, variables, etc. Unfortunately, `select` is one of those reserved keywords, so you will need to change the name of your function to something else, as shown below.

For a list of reserved keywords, you can view those [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Modal</title>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    function show(p) {
      alert(p);
      document.getElementById(p).style.display = "block";
      return 1;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectRs(Rs) {
      alert("HAHAHAHAH" + Rs);
      document.write("HAHAHAHAH <br>" + Rs);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  BMW : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="BMW" onclick="show('BMWModels')"><br> Ferrari : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Ferrari" onclick="show('FerrariModels')"><br> Maruti : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Maruti" onclick="show('MarutiModels')"><br>

  <div id="BMWModels" style="display: none">
    <!--HERE IF I WRITE onclick="alert('price for this model is xxxxx ')" 
    then it works properly..-->
    <!-- 
      I tried calling the function from browser console then it works properly please kindly guide me..
    -->
    BMW Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="selectRs(1)"><br> BMW Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> BMW Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br>

  </div>

  <div id="FerrariModels" style="display: none">
    Ferrari Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Ferrari Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Ferrari Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br>
  </div>

  <div id="MarutiModels" style="display: none">
    Maruti Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Maruti Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Maruti Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to change the name of the function `select` to something else like `selectRs` since `select` is one of the [`reserved words`](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) in javascript.

```js
function show(p) {
  alert(p);
  document.getElementById(p).style.display = "block";
  return 1;
}

function selectRs(Rs) {
  alert("HAHAHAHAH" + Rs);
  document.write("HAHAHAHAH <br>" + Rs);
}
```

```html
BMW : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="BMW" onclick="show('BMWModels')"><br> Ferrari : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Ferrari" onclick="show('FerrariModels')"><br> Maruti : <input type="radio" name="cars" id="Maruti" onclick="show('MarutiModels')"><br>

<div id="BMWModels" style="display: none">
  <!--HERE IF I WRITE onclick="alert('price for this model is xxxxx ')" 
    then it works properly..-->
  <!-- 
      I tried calling the function from browser console then it works properly please kindly guide me..
    -->
  BMW Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="selectRs(1)"><br> BMW Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> BMW Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="BMW" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br>

</div>

<div id="FerrariModels" style="display: none">
  Ferrari Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Ferrari Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Ferrari Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="fmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br>
</div>

<div id="MarutiModels" style="display: none">
  Maruti Model 1 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Maruti Model 2 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br> Maruti Model 3 : <input type="radio" name="Mmodels" onclick="selectRs('10000000 Rs')"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Why I can't name it select.

Comment: But you should tell the OP why he should change the `select` to another name, not just let him blindly follow your instructions.

Comment: @ths I did add a explanation, I think elle's edit actually removed my update

Answer (score 1):

Try this example where you can still use `select` as function name :)

```js
function select(e) {
  console.log('currency selected =', this.value);
}

var inps = document.getElementsByName('currency');
for (var i = 0; inps.length > i; i++) {
  inps[i].onclick = select;
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="currency" value="USD"/>USD</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="currency" value="INR"/>INR</label>
```

P.S. being `select` as one of the reserved keywords use of such names are discouraged.

Comment: Yep!! When I tried to print a function name i.e. foo where foo() is a function then in the output I got whole function definition.